# Recreating project with deleted project name and key in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I have deleted a project from sonarqube. After that I have tried to create a project with deleted project name and key. In jenkins it is showing Analysis is successful but in server I am not able to see project.

What I have to do to see project in sonarqube

Comment: Have you checked logs of the [Background Task](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Background+Tasks) on SonarQube side ?

Comment: In properties file i have added (sonar.analysis.mode=preview 
sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true) these properties.it is because of that.